# How different are "come up to mind", "come down to mind" and "come to mind"?

Tags: word-difference

According to the hits of google search "come to mind" is most often used and "come down to mind" is least used.

What difference have these three phrases?
Should I only use the "come to mind" that is most used?

Comment: Could you add some examples using "come up/down to mind" for reference? Google word searches out of context sometimes have an explanation other than the intended usage.

Comment: I used the "come up to mind", but I heard a friend of mine uses "come down to mind", and I googled the phrase then I found the "come to mind". It seems that we should just use "come to mind".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Come down to mind* and *come up to mind* are extremely rare, at least in the United States. In fact, I've never heard anyone write or say either of those phrases.

*Come to mind* is pretty common, though. It is defined in The Free Dictionary:

> To enter into one's consciousness or be
>   remembered.
>
> *Do I know a good barber? No one comes to mind right now.*

Another definition is the following:

> To enter or appear in your thoughts.
>
> *Mention fashion and Kate's name
>   comes to mind.*

I would say, feel free to use *come to mind*.

But *come down to mind* or *come up to mind* wouldn't make much sense to people.

Comment: I think the same applies for British English.